# Find all incongruent solutions to $21x \equiv 14 \pmod{91}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find all incongruent solutions to $21x \equiv 14 \pmod{91}$.

I am able to work out the solution using Euclidean algorithm techniques,  but the signs on the expression do not match up with the initial expression when I check my work.  So by the linear congruence theorem, my solution has to satisfy: $$21x - 91y = 14$$  but after going through the process with the $\gcd(21, 91)$ my expression ends up as $$91 - 21(4) = 7$$ which I multiply by $2$ to get: $$91(2) - 21(8) = 14$$ 
Which would mean my solution has to have a negative somewhere in it. I can "put" a negative on one of my values and the original expression would be satisfied but that is not what I obtained through the work I did. Is the confusion in signs occurring on purpose or am I treating something wrong?

Comment: Just rewrite the final equation as $21 (-8) - 91 (-2) = 14$.  It has the form you gave for the linear congruence theorem, and from it you see that $x=-8$ is a solution.  It only remains to see that all other solutions are congruent to -8 modulo 13, so that, for instance, 5 is another solution.

Comment: but I didn't get $(-2)$ as my other solution, i got $2$ so how am I able to switch that to a $(-2)$?

Comment: In your formula, 2 is the number multiplying 91. But in the linear congruence theorem above, the solution x is supposed to be the number multiplying 21. That number is -8, which is a solution

Comment: But wouldn't the fact that I got  a positive 2 for the solution to y and applying both solutions i. e.  $x = (-8)$ and $y= 2$ to the expression from the linear congruence theorem to check if the solution i obtained actually satisfies it and after doing so I see that those specific values: $x = (-8)$, $y= 2$ do not satisfy the expression. Doesn't that mean that my solution is invalid?

Comment: Barry's solution is your solution, just rewritten in a form that fits the original congruence: $$91(2) - 21(8) = 14$$ $$(-21(8)) - (-91(2)) = 14$$ $$21(-8) - 91(-2) = 14$$. Now you have it in the form you gave from the lineare congruence theorem. Personally, I would rewrite it further as $$21(-8) - 14 = 91(-2)$$, as this is the definition of $$21(-8) \equiv 14 \mod 91$$

Comment: That clarifies things. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the congruence 
$$21x \equiv 14 \pmod{91} \tag{1}$$ 
is equivalent to the equation 
$$21x = 14 + 91t, t \in \mathbb{Z} \tag{2}$$
If we divide each term of equation 2 by $7$, we obtain the equivalent equation
$$3x = 2 + 13t, t \in \mathbb{Z}$$
which is equivalent to the congruence
$$3x \equiv 2 \pmod{13} \tag{3}$$
Hence, 
$$21x \equiv 14 \pmod{91} \Longleftrightarrow 3x \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$$
Since $\gcd(3, 13) = 1$, the congruence $3x \equiv 2 \pmod{13}$ has a solution.  We can find it by applying the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).
\begin{align*}
13 & = 4 \cdot 3 + 1\\
3 & = 3 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Solving for $1$ in terms of $3$ and $13$ yields 
$$1 = 13 - 4 \cdot 3$$
Thus,
$$1 \equiv -4 \cdot 3 \pmod{13} \implies -4 \equiv 3^{-1} \pmod{13}$$
Therefore, if we multiply both sides of congruence 3 by $-4$, we obtain
$$x \equiv -8 \pmod{13}$$
To find all the solutions of congruence 1, we must find all the solutions of the inequality
$$0 \leq -8 + 13t < 91$$
in the integers.
\begin{align*}
0 & \leq -8 + 13t < 91\\
8 & \leq 13t < 99\\
\end{align*}
Hence, $1 \leq t \leq 7$.  Therefore, the solutions of the congruence $21x \equiv 14 \pmod{91}$ are
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 5 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 18 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 31 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 44 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 57 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 70 \pmod{91}\\
  & \equiv 83 \pmod{91}
\end{align*} 
which you can check by direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler method to execute the problem is to first simplify it using gcd of $(21, 14, 91)$ as divisor (gcd=7). The equation becomes $3x≡2 (mod 13)$. Use values 0 through 12 to find solution. Extended Euclidean Algorithm will be useful when divisor and dividend are large numbers. The equation gets solution when $f(x) = f(5): (5*3)-2 = 13$; $13|13$. Now take all multiples of 13 adding each time 5; to get $5, 18, 31, 44, 57, 70$ and $83$ as illustrated above (till value less than main divisor i.e. 91). These all provide required solutions to the equation by substituting these values to x: $21x≡14 (mod 91)$
Prof. Dr. Shabir Ahmad Mir

Answer (score -1):

$$21x\equiv 14\pmod{91}\stackrel{:7}\iff 3x\equiv 2\equiv 15\pmod{13}$$

$$\stackrel{:3}\iff x\equiv 5\pmod{13}$$

All integers of the form $13k+5$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$ are the solutions.